# which directive in apache's conf determines mime-type from file extension?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

**Background** :So in an attempt to learn apache, Im following along with the exercises in the book "Apache: The definitive guide". As part of these exercises, we're incrementally building up the httpd.conf file.

**Problem:** my html is getting served as plaintext. The mime-type is plain\text even though the file extension is .html

I'd like to know what directive i must add for it to pick up the right extension
Here's my conf file :

```
User webuser  
Group webgroup
ServerName my586
DocumentRoot /usr/www/APACHE3/site.first/htdocs
TransferLog logs/access_log
Listen 80
```

**Additional Info to help diagnose the problem:**

The exercise also mentions adding the following directive:
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

But this gives the following error:
    Invalid command 'TypesConfig', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
this led me to the believe it had something to d with the mod_mime module, but i havent been able to make it work through that either

**Update:** Interestingly, I presumed, images\jpegs would be shown as plain text too, but it shows them fine, i.e. sets the correct mime type on them.

Comment: Is this apache1 or apache2?

Comment: this is apache2

Comment: So I elimintaed the posibilit of this having anything to do with the mod_mime. I made the TypesConfig directive work by adding the following directive :
 #Include /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.load
#Include /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.conf

But the original problem of .html extensions displaying as plaintext still remains. From what I can gather, apache is supposed to behave this way by default (change mime-type based on extension)

Comment: Lines starting with a "#" are ignored. The "#" signifies the start of a comment. If you added lines starting with that they won't do anything :)

Comment: oops, the #'s were not intended. (looks like i miss my c\c++ days of #includes)

Answer (score 2):

```
AddType image/gif .gif
```

It seems that if you want TypesConfig to work, you will need to make sure you have mod_mime loaded.

Answer (score 0):

On linux distributions, you have a file /etc/mime.types which contains mime type definitions.
It is loaded with the command TypesConfig after the load of the mime module :

```
LoadModule mime_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mime.so
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
</IfModule>
```

Inside the IfModule, you can also add charset and language declarations.